# How to iterate through a Word document and bold certain sentences?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am sending string expressions to Microsoft Word through my application.
I want to make some of these strings bold.
In the figure below, I can only make the first item bold. I can't bold any following items in the array.

```cs
Range range6 = doc.Content; 
range6.Find.Execute("{GDRNY}"); 
range6.Text = agtBaslik5;

range6.Font.Bold = 0;

object objStart = range6.Start;
object objEnd = range6.Start + agtBaslik5.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);

Range rngBold = doc.Range(ref objStart, ref objEnd); rngBold.Bold = 1;
```

The "dummy data" I enter into the application:

1. XXXXXX

   XXXXXX...
2. XXXXXX

   XXXXXX...
3. XXXXX

   XXXXXX...

I then get the following output:

**1. XXXXXX**

XXXXXX...

2. XXXXXX

XXXXXX....

3. XXXXX

XXXXXX....

...

The desired output I want is:

**1. XXXXXX**

XXXXXX....

**2. XXXXXX**

XXXXXX....

**3. XXXXX**

XXXXXX....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's only going through the first sentence of your Word doc.

What might be helpful is checking out the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-define-and-select-ranges-in-documents?view=vs-2019) on iterating through the Sentences[i] and setting it to bold on every uneven number

I hope this helps a bit!